# Formatting a Python string payload value for request

Tags: python, string

I am trying to replace the values in the payload_1 below of a python request; with param values passed dynamically. payload_2 should look like payload_1 only the values of the keys Date and Routing should be variables i can pass in.

I cannot change the header `'Content-Type':'text/plain'` as the server expects it this way

The param values are TODAY'S_DATE in that format and ROUTING_VALUE;

```
payload_1 = "{\n    \"ABCD\": [\n  {\n \"Date\": \"20200-03-08T00:00:00.000000\",\n  \"type\": \"acctfile\",\n    \"Routing\": \"routing_\"\n  }\n ]\n}"
payload_2 = "{\n    \"ABCD\": [\n  {\n \"Date\": \"TODAY'S_DATE\",\n  \"type\": \"acctfile\",\n    \"Routing\": \"ROUTING_VALUE\"\n  }\n ]\n}"
```

The end goal is to pass this payload into this snippet below.

```
url = "https://....."
headers = {'userToken': 'token', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: "I tried using + to concat the escapes and the param strings but not working." -- what do you mean by "not working"? What does the desired payload look like?

Comment: I mean i tried to split the string into several parts and pass the variables enclosed with "+"

Comment: I repeat, "What does the desired payload look like?"

Comment: the desired payload looks like payload_1

Comment: If you already know what the payload looks like, then what's the problem? You say you're trying to concat something but you have not shown that attempt so we cannot guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load your string as a JSON object, then it is trivial to replace the values therein.

```py
import datetime
import json

template = "{\n    \"ABCD\": [\n  {\n \"Date\": \"20200-03-08T00:00:00.000000\",\n  \"type\": \"acctfile\",\n    \"Routing\": \"ACCT_1442309\"\n  }\n ]\n}"

o = json.loads(template)

date, routing = datetime.date.today(), 'ABCDEF'

d = o['ABCD'][0]

d['Date'] = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000000')
d['Routing'] = routing

payload = json.dumps(o, indent=4)
print(payload)
```

Comment: genius ;)  Thank you so much!